# Unix/Linux, Delete comments from lines

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, comments

I need to delete/remove comments from a user-input line without deleting any codes. So for example:

```
mail -s 'text' brown < text #comments
```

How do I remove the comments and leave the code intact?
I can delete lines that begin with #, but not if it begins somewhere in the middle of the lines.

I tried:

```
echo $line | sed -e 's/\
```

but it does not work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Also, how to detect cases in which # is not used to begin a comment?
For example quoted # and line of code that ends with # since they are not comments.

```
echo $line | sed -e  '/^#/d'
```

In this line, the # is not used as a comment, but as part of code. I figure out that I need to detect that if # is within quotes or does not have a whitespace character before the #. How do I leave the output as it is?

Comment: I would like to know how you think you can remove the comment from my example file in my post automatically.

Comment: Doing this job properly is impossible unless you take into account the lexical structure of a shell script.  You need to handle single quoted strings, double quoted strings, variable expansions such as `$#` and `${#variable}` and `${variable#head}`, and here documents (as a start).  When you can detect those accurately, in all their glory (remember, quoted strings can extend over multiple lines!), then you can start to detect comments.  Note that `echo a#b` echoes three characters plus a newline.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all from `#` to end of line using this `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/#.*$/,"")}1' file
```

But if you have file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
pidof tail #See if tail is running
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then  #start loop
   awk '{print " # "$8}' file >tmp # this is my code
fi # end of loop
awk -F# '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file > tmp2
a=a+1 # increment a
```

There are no way you can remove the comment automatically without destroying some.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is it also deletes anything that is not part of comment. So for example: code/#/code . Since the # is part of a code, I don't want it to delete anything from that line.

Comment: @chipunpui Can you then tell me how a program should see the difference on `#` used as a comment, and not as some part of a code.  You then need some logic to understand that the text is human information about the code.

Comment: Note that this destroys any use of `$#` or `${#variable}` or various other constructions that use a `#`, not to mention quoted strings containing a `#`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that was some of my point. There are no way to remove comments automatically.  Some human has to see if it comment or part of the code.

Comment: It can be done, but it requires a full-scale parser for the shell language (or, at least, a lexical scanner that is cognizant of all the syntax rules for the shell language). It can't reasonably be done using `sed`; it would be extremely messy using `awk`.  In fact, it would be fairly messy regardless of the language used to implement the parser/scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider what almost always comes after a comment in bash.

```
#comment...
#another comment
```

A line break! Which is effectively a character. So, all you have to do is add a wildcard after your #, to include the actual comment text, then put a line break 'character' at the end. <strike>You'll actually need to use \n rather than trying to hit Enter.</strike> Unfortunately I'm not on linux at the moment, and sometimes delimiters (the backslash) don't work properly. <strike>Trying something like  `\n`   might work, or maybe using $'\n'.</strike>

EDIT: With regex ^ will indicate the start of a new line, while $ indicates the end.

As for not deleting actual code, matching for a space immediately followed by # should work. I would match for a space OR line break preceding the #.

At any rate, please be sure not to accidentally ruin whatever you're working on, just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I am asking. I just don't know how since I'm still learning about sed/awk. I initially thought to parse the string by character and check whether the character preceding # is a space or a line break, but that is a lot of work.