# Grep expression is excluding some matches that I want

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, grep

I'm working on a program that extracts the comments from a bash file and outputs them to a new file.

I need to ignore #'s encased in ' ' or " " quotations which I think I have done correctly.

```
grep -oe "[^\'\"\\]#[^\'\"].*" somefile >> somecomments
```

This extracts comments that are preceded by some text fine, e.g.

```
echo Sum: $Sum    # Displays the sum
```

will be converted to "# Displays the sum" in the output file. 
The problem is that lines beginning with # are now excluded for some reason e.g.

```
# Name
# Date
```

will not show up in the output file at all.

How do I fix my expression so that I can still exclude quotations in front of the # but have it extract lines beginning with #?

Comment: You will not get this to work.  Comments starts with `#`, but `#` may also be a part of the `code`.  You need a large list of exception that can say that this `#` is part of code, ignore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix/Linux, Delete comments from lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601260/unix-linux-delete-comments-from-lines)

Answer (score 0):

Check if following works for you:

```
grep -oe "[^\'\"\\]#[^\'\"].*" -e "^#.*" somefile >> somecomments
```

But as one of the comment say, you will have to take care of many exceptions.

What if there is a statement like

`echo '<space> ########### Following code does this #########<space>'`

You shall have to take all those chances in mind.